# Cannot access databases on heroku rediscloud

Tags: ruby, heroku, redis

Using a [rediscloud 1GB plan](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud), I cannot seem to connect to a specified siloed database. E.g., in ruby (using ruby 2.2.10, redis ruby library v3.3.5):

```
redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'], db: 4)
redis.get 'foo' # => Redis::CommandError: ERR DB index is out of range
```

Similar result is obtained when specifying the db in the `url` parameter:

```
redis = Redis.new(url: "#{ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']}/4")
redis.get 'foo' # => Redis::CommandError: ERR DB index is out of range
```

I have not encountered this problem with other redis instances. Am I misunderstanding something about redis, dbs, or rediscloud?

Comment: Is the `REDISCLOUD_URL` actually set in your Heroku environment? Does it return a full URL with a `redis://` protocol and a port? Did you try to concatenate the DB number with the URL like this: `Redis.new(url: "#{ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']}/4")`?

Comment: Yes. It returns full protocol and port. If I initialize `Redis` with `db: 0`, the client works as expected. I get the same error DB index error, however if I specify the Redis database as you suggested (by appending "/4").

Comment: I'll also note that specifying "/0" database in the url works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, it looks like rediscloud is a product that does not automatically come with databases. It requires that you manually add them, notwithstanding that the plan indicates that the databases are included. [Relevant documentation.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#adding-redis-databases-to-your-plan)